# IP address of network computer

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

The program I'm coding connects to another program via a network-API, and I believe it's called a socket connection. I specify the IP: 127.0.0.1, and the Port, which must match what I set in that program.  Now, this works fine. But what if I want to have the program running on another computer on a network?

I have set up a wireless home network, and file sharing works between the two computers. I thought I could just run cmd>ipconfig to get the IP of the other computer, but for some reason the ipconfig will not run on it. Just gives an error.   How do I now determine the correct IP to use for this type of network connection?

PS: I'm running XP Pro.

Comment: I am sure you mean `IP`, and not `API`.

Comment: "some other reason" ? Does it throw an error? You can just look in the network adapter/network connection properties in the taskbar to find the3 IP.

Comment: Can you post error content? Make sure you use ipconfig on remote computer, it can only get ip of local machine's NICs

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming problem or are you trying to find/guess the remote IP with your code? **=> should go to superuser.com**

Comment: I did mean API.. I connect (the program I code) to another program through an API connection.    And cmd>ipconfig doesn't work. I can't either seem to find this by right-clicking "wireless network connection"  in Network Connections..

Comment: Well it's not programming "code" question. It's just to know the IP so I can specify it in my program. If that's not ok to ask, then sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the computer name instead of the IP (but, this depends what you're working on). To see what the computer name is right click My Computer / Properties.

Or, you can see it's IP simply by pinging it:

```
ping MyPCName
```

In the response you'll get the resolved IP address, the way computer you ran it on sees it.

Answer (score 0):

Open network connections (Start -> Settings -> Control Panel -> Network Connections) and find there your wireless connection. Left click and select Properties. Then follow the Advanced tab and there you propapbly will find your IP.

Comment: This also may be done with "ipconfig /a" command. BTW, as far as I understand the question, program way to obtain IP address is required.

Comment: well, it doesn't seem to show. I can click on TCP/IP in the general tab, but it only shows that IP is set to automatic, and not showing the actual IPs.

Comment: thing is: when i try to run cmd > ipconfig (from run) .. It doesnt run like normal. it says:  "An internal error occured" A unit connected to the system does not work..  (Or something similar; it is not English XP)    So I can't get it from there.

Answer (score 0):

`ipconfig` shows you the address of your computer. You can use `ipconfig` on the other computer to check its IP address. Then instead of `127.0.0.1` use that address. There is `ipconfig /all` that show much more information, usable if you have more network cards, want to check MAC address etc, but this is information about computer this command work on.

Comment: Then get it to work, there should be a root cause for the issue. Simplest way is usually to backup data, wipe and reload the Windows installation, it's likely faulty and/or has driver conflicts and that could take an infinite time to resolve if you're not familiar with the system.

Comment: Thanks, but I think simplest way is just to ignore it. I have better things to spend my time on.  :)